# ASP.NET MVC3: Displaying Date in correct format with JQuery DatePicker and editorFor/TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, date-format

In my model I have:

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately, It only applies to EditorFor, but I cant assign the EditorFor a class, to enable Jquery Datetime picker, as there is no `htmlAttributes` parameter.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "datePicker", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

So the first shows only the date, but has no datepicker.
The second shows the time too 00:00 but has a datetimepicker.

**Note:** Dont just say, use `model.StartDate.ToString("mm/DD/yyyy")`. It does not work.

How Can I set just the Date. But have a timepicker for it And have readonly, so I cant type any numbers in it.

Comment: I'm interested in an MVC level solution to this. I ended up resorting to standard html input elements to achieve this effect in my own project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the jquery UI datepicker, which rather than append a class tag, I set the default date format via:

```
    $(function () {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    });
```

Then to bind it to the input element:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker();
    });
```

Hope that helps. And thats on the EditorFor mvc tag.

Comment: Thanks, Yea assigning it via fieldname seems to be the only way, as you cant seem to set htmlattributes aka classes. And using my displaycode, it can then apply the format of the model, and use the datetimepicker via this. Still cant set readonly though. My Time picker is another problem. Ive overcome this with `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new {@Value = Model.EndTime.ToString().Substring(0,5), @class = "timePicker", @readonly = "readonly" })`. Madness